# Enviar dos parametros por post desde Angular a PHP

Tags: php, angular, base-de-datos, typescript

Estoy intentando mandar desde un datepicker, 2 fechas a un PHP a través de un servicio pero me está dando error y el error dice que ocurre un error de sintaxis en el JSON y yo eso no lo toco, asique no se que puede ser.
Ahora mismo estoy enviando los dos parámetros por separado pero he intentado también meterlos en un array en el componente y mandar el array y ya en el php acceder a cada fecha pero también me da error.

LA VISTA:

```
<div id="contenedorTOP">
  <div id="campos">
    
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Rango de fechas DD/MM/AA</mat-label>
      <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
        <input matStartDate placeholder="Inicio" />
        <input matEndDate placeholder="Fin" />
      </mat-date-range-input>
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="caja">
    <ol>
      <li class="videojuego" *ngFor="let videojuego of listadoVideojuegos">
        <div>
          <img
            src="{{ videojuego.imagen }}"
            alt="Portada de {{ videojuego.nombre }}"
            class="imagenesTOP"
          />
          <p>{{ videojuego.nota_media }}</p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Función del componente:

```
public mostrarPorFechas(){
this.videojuegoService.mostrarPorFechas(this.FechaInicial, this.FechaFinal).subscribe({
  next: (data) => {
    this.listadoVideojuegos = data;
  },
});


}
```

El servicio para enviar los datos:

```
public mostrarPorFechas(FechaInicial: Date, FechaFinal: Date):Observable<Videojuego>{
return this.httpClient.post<Videojuego>(`${this.baseUrl}/mostrarPorFechas.php`, {FechaInicial, FechaFinal } );


}
```

El php:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");

$fechas = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


if (!$fechas) {
    exit("No se recibe ningun dato");
}

$bd = include_once "bd.php";
$sentencia = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM videojuegos fecha BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-02-02' ORDER BY fecha ");
$videojuegos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo json_encode($videojuegos);
```

[image: Este es el error]

Answer (score 0):

Me arriesgaría a decir que lo que está mal formado es la consulta SQL:

```
"SELECT * FROM videojuegos fecha BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND '2022-02-02' ORDER BY fecha "
```

Cuando decir `videojuegos fecha` estás haciendo una especie de TABLA AS, como indicando que a la tabla videojuegos la vas a nombrar "fecha" adentro de la consulta,, podrías cambiar en el `ORDER BY fecha` por `ORDER BY fecha.id` por ejemplo, o directamente `ORDER BY videojuegos.id`. Es por esto que la respuesta del PHP no está en el formato que vos esperas,, me arriesgaría también a decir que debe devolver un error o vacio.

Posterior a esta modificación, lo que estaria bueno que veas es que la respuesta (en pestaña network del navegador) del php, sea efectivamente en formato JSON.